# What are the standard term(s) for 'Home' (used for web site home page link) in the world's major languages?

Tags: language, internationalisation, localization

Arbitrary selection of languages: French, German, Italian, Russian, Mandarin, Cantonese, Japanese, Korean, Arabic, Turkish, Hindu, Portuguese, Dutch.

Language - Term

English - Home

Comment: Russian — Главная (literally Main)

Comment: This question is more about languages and translation than UX.

Comment: Here they come, I can hear them scratching at the gates, noooOOOOoooo!

Comment: In Dutch, the English word is used, so: Dutch - Home.

Comment: In all languages: **Upper, left logo**...

Comment: German: "Startseite", "Start", "Home"

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this with a pictorial representation of the home page.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Pwned.​​​​​​​​​​